# call API after v-show condition has been met

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

In my app if a user is not authenticated a login component is loaded. After the user authenticates the login component is replaced with a form which is being populated with data from an API.

The API is getting called when the page loads for the first time and before the user authenticates, the form does not get the data after the user logs in. I want to call the API after the user authenticates. Here is my code:

```html
    <template v-if="!authenticated">
        <Login />
      </template>

      <template v-if="authenticated">
        <div
          v-show="updateResponse.statusText=='Accepted'"
          align="center"
          justify="center"
        >Your post has been submitted.</div>

        <div v-show="updateResponse.length==0">
         //template for the form
        </div>
      </template>
```

```html
<script>
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar.vue";
import Login from "@/components/Login.vue";

import axios from "axios";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "RestaurantEdit",

  components: {
    NavBar,
    Login,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      jsonResponse: [],
      updateResponse: [],
      values: [],
    };
  },

  activated() {
    this.callAPI(), console.log("activated");
  },

  watch: {
    $route: "callAPI",
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      authenticated: "auth/authenticated",
    }),
  },

  methods: {
    updateRestaurant() {
      axios
        .put(
          "/restaurant/" + this.$route.params.id + "/edit/",
          this.jsonResponse
        )
        .then(
          (response) => (
            (this.updateResponse = response), console.log(this.updateResponse)
          )
        )
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },

    callAPI() {
      (this.updateResponse = []),
        axios
          .get("/restaurant/" + this.$route.params.id + "/edit/")
          .then((response) => (this.jsonResponse = response.data));
      console.log("activated watching");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Put the watch on `authenticated` instead of `$route`.

Comment: did you try with async await? i would set the first api call in the mounted method, then the authenticate method in a separate async method and login as async to... then you make a new third method and in there you call const authenticae = await authenticate() and then const callApi = await callApi() as methods both of them. it should work, if i understand your question right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) or [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

For example, using watchers, you can add a watcher to the `authenticated` computed property, and depending on it's status, call your API accordingly. Here's how you can do it:

```js
export default {
  name: "RestaurantEdit",

  components: {
    NavBar,
    Login,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      jsonResponse: [],
      updateResponse: [],
      values: [],
    };
  },

  watch: {
    authenticated(val, oldVal) {
      if(/* check if authenticated */) {
        this.callAPI();
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      authenticated: "auth/authenticated",
    }),
  },

  methods: {
    updateRestaurant() {
      axios
        .put(
          "/restaurant/" + this.$route.params.id + "/edit/",
          this.jsonResponse
        )
        .then(
          (response) => (
            (this.updateResponse = response), console.log(this.updateResponse)
          )
        )
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },

    callAPI() {
      (this.updateResponse = []),
        axios
          .get("/restaurant/" + this.$route.params.id + "/edit/")
          .then((response) => (this.jsonResponse = response.data));
      console.log("activated watching");
    },
  },
};
```

And with custom events, you need to emit an event from the component. In this case, it would be the `<Login />` component. When the authentication is successful you can emit an event in the `<Login />` component using `this.$emit('login-success')` and in the `<RestaurantEdit />` component template you need to listen for it like `<Login @login-success="callAPI" />`.

Comment: I tried using watcher but get this error : 'val' is defined but never used. 'oldVal' is defined but never used. In the documentation they don't use the old and new values. So I am not sure what's causing the error.

Comment: See the code, I've left a comment `/* check if authenticated */` where you can use the values available. I don't know how you are making sure a user is authenticated, left space there for you to implement that. 
Here `val` is the value of `authenticated` after a change, and `oldVal` is the previous value.
That error is the linter telling you that you simply aren't using those variables in your code, so you should get rid of them.